# Rspec before block parameters?

Tags: rspec

I need to define before(:each) block for my rspec, but in this block there're some variables which should be determined by each example. I googled but didn't see a way to do so. Could anybody give me an example?

```
before(:each) do
  subject.stub(:abc) {double(price: 11)}
end
```

Here 11 should actually be a variable given by each example.

Answer (score 2):

The `before` blocks always get executed prior to the examples, so it's not possible for the latter to impact the former. However, instead of trying to share a `before` block in this way across examples, you can share a "shared example" and pass a parameter to it, as described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples#passing-parameters-to-a-shared-example-group

Comment: The link provided is broken.  Very important to not use links if possible.